# React::ServerRendering::PrerenderError in... Rails 5, React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `Rails 5` with `react-rails` gem. I want to use server-side rendering, but I see this error:

> React::ServerRendering::PrerenderError in Home#index
>
> Encountered error "# ExecJS::ProgramError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'serverRender' of undefined" when prerendering Main with {}

This is my `/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

This is `javascripts/components.jsx`:

```
class Main extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

and this is the view:

```
<%= react_component('Main', {}, {prerender: true}) %>
```

Without `prerender` option, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and here's how I solved it

run command `rails generate react:install`

This will create the components folder and some required files under your javascripts/ dir.

Now, place your `components.jsx` in `/assets/javascripts/componets` directory

refresh the page.

I'm running rails 4.2.10 and haven't tested rails 5 but I'm guessing this should do the trick.

Let me know how you get on